# How to capture a JFrame's close button click event?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I want to call a method `confirmExit()` when the red close button of the title bar of a JFrame is clicked.

How can I capture that event?

I'd also like to prevent the window from closing if the user chooses not to proceed.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/*Some piece of code*/
frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, 
            "Are you sure you want to close this window?", "Close Window?", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
});
```

If you also want to prevent the window from closing unless the user chooses 'Yes', you can add:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: If want the program to only close this frame and not entirely stop, use `frame.dispose()` instead of `System.exit(0)`

Answer (score 26):

Override windowClosing Method.

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
```

It is invoked when a window is in the process of being closed. The close operation can be overridden at this point.

Comment: Will this work if the user closes the application (for example, by hitting Cmd + Q on a Mac)? Does the class that implements this method have to declare `implements WindowListener` for this code to work?  If so, it might be good to include that in the answer.  Otherwise this is an elegant solution.

Comment: @brandaemon If you add this line of code to the top of your main() method "System.setProperty("apple.eawt.quitStrategy", "CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS");" then it will call the windowListener when Cmd + Q is pressed on mac.

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
jdialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("jdialog window closed event received");
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("jdialog window closing event received");
    }
});
```

Source: https://alvinalexander.com/java/jdialog-close-closing-event

Answer (score 1):

```
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

also works. First create a JFrame called frame, then add this code underneath.

Comment: But this does not execute the `confirmExit()` method as the OP would like it

Comment: It does the same thing though

Comment: No, I don't want to simply close the program. I want to do something before it happens.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't know that.

Comment: Although this is not the right answer, for someone who just want a simple solution this is useful. +1.

Comment: "What I want to do is to call ... `confirmExit()` when [the X] is clicked." And the previous comment is unrelated to OQ.

Comment: This is exactly the contrary, add `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` to have a control with `confirmExit`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I put as a menu option where I made a button on a `JFrame` to display another `JFrame`. I wanted only the new frame to be visible, and not to destroy the one behind it. I initially hid the first `JFrame`, while the new one became visible. Upon closing of the new `JFrame`, I disposed of it followed by an action of making the old one visible again.

Note: The following code expands off of Ravinda's answer and `ng` is a `JButton`:

```java
ng.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    setVisible(false);
    JFrame j = new JFrame("NAME");
    j.setVisible(true);
    j.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            setVisible(true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

It will work.